# Excel - Changing design of bars in charts

Tags: excel

In excel charts can we change design of bars from

[image]

to

[image]

**Background:** I have taken agile project plan excel template from https://www.smartsheet.com/agile-project-management-excel-templates, but I didnt like the bars without arrows and hence I want to change these bars to look something like bars in https://www.smartsheet.com/agile-project-management-excel-templates#agile-product-roadmap-template

Lead here is appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to have anything to do about programming, rather about how to use a software (excel). It would thus be more suited to a site like SuperUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half... Let me show and you decide :)

This arrow is not a chart object. It's a shape, a drawing:

[image]

However, we can use shape object in Excel charts.

Remove text (you'll see in the last picture why) and Copy the excel object (picture above).

Mark the chart series you want to replace (notice I marked all of them, small circles)

[image]

Then just paste :D!!

Notice one bar has a border line, just click on the bar -> "Fill & Line" -> "Border" -> "No Line" to hide the border line around your shape object.

[image]

You can do it individually with different colours. When the graph changes the size of your bars changes too (according to your data). It's a bit more "maintenance" but looks better. General rule, the better it looks, the more "special" it is (more manual involvement)...

[image]

Comment: Where can I find this arrow like object in excel?

Comment: Also when I try to change the color the arrow looking object changes back to those rectangular bars.

Comment: 1. You need to [create it by yourself](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/draw-or-edit-a-freeform-shape-44d7bb9d-c05c-4e1c-a486-e35fc322299b) or just copy the shape from the template workbook to your new one (I did that). 2. You need to change the colour before you paste it. I would recommend these kind of solution more as presentation rather than daily use graphs. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help